# Rotate transformation matrix to match reflection vector

Tags: python, vector, numpy, matrix, turtle-graphics

There are a couple of ball-bounce related questions on stackoverflow that i've looked through, however none of them seem to get me past my predicament.  I have a turtle cursor defined by a transformation matrix that intersects a line in 3d space.  What I want is to rotate the cursor, that is, the transformation matrix, at the point of intersection so that it's new direction matches the reflection vector.  I have functions that will get both the reflection vector `R` from the incident vector `V` and the normal of the reflecting line `N`.  I normalize each before evaluating:

```
N,V=unit_vector(N),unit_vector(V)
R = -2*(np.dot(V,N))*N - V
R=unit_vector(R)
```

My transformation matrix, `T` is in a numpy array:

```
array([[ -0.84923515,   -0.6        ,   0.        ,   3.65341878],
       [  0.52801483,  -0.84923515,   0.        ,  25.12882224],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   1.        ]])
```

How can I transform T by R to get the correct direction vector?  I've found and used the R2_vect function from [here](http://svn.gna.org/svn/relax/tags/1.3.4/maths_fns/rotation_matrix.py) to get a rotation matrix from one vector to another but only a few of the resulting reflections appear correct when i send them to vtk to render.  I'm asking  about this here because I seem to be reaching the limit of what I can remember from my already shaky linear algebra.  Thanks for any information.

Comment: "I have a vector defined by a transformation matrix that intersects another vector in 3d space" - that doesn't make sense.  please explain clearly what the transformation matrix does.

Comment: I am not sure, the matrix is 4x4, the vector in 3d space has likely 3 dimensions. I don't see what the OP means as well

Comment: @flebool in graphics programming transformations are sometimes written with 4 components and an extra "1" added to x,y,z coords so that translations can be included wout a separate addition.

Comment: @andrew-cooke  Question updated.  The matrix is just a transform matrix that defines a turtle cursor.  The cursor's forward direction is taken from the values in the second column of the transform matrix and multiplied by a distance to get the resulting position of the new cursor.  From there it can be rotated and moved again.

Answer (score 1):

A little extra research clarified things:   the first 3 columns of the transformation matrix represent 3 orthonormal vectors ( `x1, x2, x3` ) and the 4th column represents the coordinates in space of the cursor at given time interval.   the final row contains no data, it's just there to keep the matrix square. rotating the vectors was just a matter of removing the last row of `T`, taking the 3x3 rotation matrix from my listed function `R` and rotating each vector: `R.dot(x1), R.dot(x2), R.dot(x3)` Then I just had to composite the values back into a 4x4 matrix.